# Hypothesis Testing: Null and Alternative are two separate means?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I have a bit of experience in hypothesis testing where the null hypothesis is a certain mean and the alternative is an inequality, either greater than or less than the null hypothesis, but I have never encountered a situation like part (1) of this question where the null and alternative are two different discrete means.

Given that the standard deviation is known, would I use a Z-test? Or is there something here I'm missing. I could definitely just be overthinking it.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes theoretical discussions use one value for $H_0$ and another for $H_a$ as a matter of clarity in finding a critical value and in discussing Type I and Type II Errors.  // If it's $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ vs.$H_1: \mu > \mu_0,$ then you can find the critical value for a particular level $\alpha.$ But if you want to find the power [1 - P(Type II Err)], then you need to have a _particular_ value $\mu_a > \mu_0$ in mind.

Comment: So would I just proceed through part (1) as I usually would? using a Z-test?

Comment: For part (1) yes. And the value of $\mu_1 = 12$ gives you a head start on part (2).